# How to work from query selector to useRef in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a typewrite effect function. Now I want to show the code (the effect) in the div (typingRef), I made something like `typingRef.current = letter` but is that the same as `document.querSelector('typing').textContent = letter`? I want to work with the `ref` not the `queryselector`

```
export function Text({ children }) {
  const headingRef = React.useRef(null)
  const typingRef = React.useRef(null)
  const texts = ['websites', 'applications', 'mobile' ]
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0
    let index = 0
    let currentText = ''
    let letter = ''

    function type() {
      if (count === texts.length) {
        count = 0
      }
      currentText = texts[count]
      letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index)

      typingRef.current = letter
      if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
        count++
        index = 0
      }
      setTimeout(type, 400)
    }
    type()
  })
  return (
    <div className={styles.component}>
      <div className={styles.intro}>
        <h1 ref={headingRef} className={styles.heading}>
          { children }
        </h1>
        <div ref={typingRef} className={styles.typing} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can come up with from trying to understand your question. Try this: typingRef.current.innerHTML

```
export const Text = ({ children }) => {
  const headingRef = React.useRef(null)
  const typingRef = React.useRef(null)
  const texts = ['websites', 'applications', 'mobile' ]
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let count = 0
    let index = 0
    let currentText = ''
    let letter = ''

    function type() {
      if (count === texts.length) {
        count = 0
      }
      currentText = texts[count]
      letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index)

      typingRef.current.innerHTML = letter

      if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
        count++
        index = 0
      }
      setTimeout(type, 400)
    }
    type()
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 ref={headingRef}>
          { children }
        </h1>
        <div ref={typingRef}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```